# Close database connection

Tags: laravel

I have built an application and I have 400 concurrent users as of now.

And as checking, I am running this query in the database

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name LIKE "Threads_%" OR variable_name = "Connections"
```

[image]

1. Is this normal?
2. if it is not normal how can I close the connection after running queries. And what is 'connections' means?
3. is this live connection to the database?

I have tried and it is not working

```
DB::disconnect('mysql');
```

Comment: You should give more information about your working environment.

Comment: Last time i checked (admitted some time ago) there was a limit of about 2^16 tcp connections (just in case your clients are served via tcp - since you did not mention...). So may be it is worth investigating what "Connections" does express.

Comment: What is the session timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `connections` variable is just the number of connections mysql has received in total, the `Threads_connected` variable is the current number of open connections

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html

Comment: Thank you. I was worried it was the total current connection connected to the database.